# Google Apps Script to export svg data in cell to png file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, svg, png

I have a google sheet that is set up to generate svg data based on values in other sheets - I use this often for scorecards, leader boards etc.  I have this set up so that one cell (for the sake of this example let's say it is "Sheet1!A1") contains all the lines of code for an svg file.  I currently have a script which takes this cell and exports it as an SVG.

However, I then have the additional step of converting these svgs into pngs so I can share them on social media etc.  Does anyone know of a way to take the svg code in a cell in google sheets and export this as a PNG file?  It's definitely wishful thinking on my part, but it would be amazing if this functionality was possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- In your situation, the SVG code is put into a cell "A1" on Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to retrieve the SVG code from the cell "A1" and convert it as a PNG image.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and please set your cell as A1Notation to `range`. And, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const range = "Sheet1!A1"; // Please set your cell as A1Notation.

  const svgCode = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(range).getDisplayValue().trim();
  const temp = DriveApp.createFile("sample.svg", svgCode, MimeType.SVG);
  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This might not be required to be used.
  const url = Drive.Files.get(temp.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace("=s220", "=s1000");
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(blob.setName("sample.png"));
  // temp.setTrashed(true); // If you want to delete the SVG file, please use this line.
}
```

- When this script `myFunction()` is run, the SVG code is retrieved from a cell of "Sheet1!A1", and an SVG file is created. And, a PNG image is retrieved from the SVG file by converting using Drive API. And, the PNG file is created as a PNG file.
- In this sample, the PNG file is created in the root folder. If you want to export the PNG file to the specific folder, please modify `DriveApp.createFile(blob.setName("sample.png"))` to `DriveApp.getFolderById("###folderID###").createFile(blob.setName("sample.png"))`.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot know your `the svg code`. So, when this script cannot be used, please provide your sample `the svg code`. By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)
- [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(BlobSource))

Comment: Amazing!!  This works great!!  Seriously, thank you so much

Just one question - is there a way to set the resolution?  of the PNG?

Comment: @Nathan Taylor Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `is there a way to set the resolution? of the PNG?`, in this case, how about modifying `replace("=s220", "=s1000")` to like `replace("=s220", "=s500")`? In this case, the width is 500 pixels and the aspect ratio is not changed. If this was not the expected result of your additional question, I apologize.